# is there a way to use the return value of a function as a default value in a django filed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I want to get the value of the Product_desciption whenever I create a new entry from my admin pannel and pass it through the getimg() function and store the return value in my image filed automatically in my Forimg table.

```
class Products(models.Model):

    Code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key = True)
    Val_tech = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    UOM = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    Value = models.FloatField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Product_description


class Forimg(models.Model):

    @staticmethod
    def getimg(item):
        page = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={item}')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        item_head = soup.find('img',class_='t0fcAb')
        return item_head['src']

    products = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', width_field= 30, height_field = 40)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.products.Product_description
```

Comment: `def foo(a = fun())` when `a` stores the return value of function `fun()`

Comment: are you looking for [**`default`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#default) option?

Comment: Yes but how do i use it here?